# Possible to replace brake line fitting?

Tags: brakes

[image: Brake Piping Connection]

I wanted to replace the brake piping connection where the center and rear brake pipes meet.  The existing fittings seem rusted beyond reuse.

Is there a way I can cut off the old fitting and add new fittings?  If I do this, won't the existing brake pipes be that much shorter?  How do I take care of that?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can be done.

Cutting off the old swaged part, fitting new pipe nuts and re-swaging the ends is relatively easy with the correct tools.

I have a set, made by BluePoint that work well in tight spaces.

If you have not done it before then get some spare pipe and practice.

Brake failure due to your error is not a good outcome.

Comment: Thanks!  Is there a general name for the toolset you use?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the clamp is holding 2 unions, which each join 2 male fittings. The fittings have surface rust, probably no danger. The brake lines seem OK, I just replaced my front brake lines because they had heavy flaking rust where the washer fluid had been spilling over the years. The lines were not available and had different size fittings at each end. I purchased a flare tool kit and some fittings to modify the standard universal lines. There are 2 main flare and fitting styles: double flare and bubble flare, not interchangeable. In your case you can wire brish the surface rust, remove the clamp, and paint some rust-destroyer. It converts surface rust to a hard black surface.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how much of the pipes are corroded.

Disassemble the connections and slide the fittings back along the pipe.  If the pipe looks good and you just want to replace the connectors, you should be able to just cut off the flared ends, put new fittings on and re-flare. You will have lost very little of the pipe and they should fit back together.

If you need to cut back further, then you may need to cut out a longer section and use a couple of connectors to insert a new piece of pipe, or replace a full section of pipe all the way to the next joint.

You may find that after removing them from the bracket and giving them a clean they may not be as bad as they look.  As long as there is no pitting in the pipe and the fittings are not heavily corroded, you should be fine. The pipe can corrode inside the fittings, so disassembling them and examining the pipe is a good idea.